# Creating mean variables within data - new column

Tags: r, variables, mean

`Hello everyone,

I am trying to create a mean variable within my data.

I would like a mean value of `rp` for every month and region (consisting of `code`) times the amount of years in my data frame.

This is a bit of the data I am working with:

`structure(list(month = c("JAN", "FEV", "MAR", "ABR", "MAI", "JUN", "JUL", "AGO", "SET", "OUT", "NOV", "DEZ", "JAN", "FEV"), year = c(2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L), code = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AM", "AM"), region = c("NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "NE", "N", "N"), month_num = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L), rp = c(151.351257324219, 150.433822631836, 145.326431274414, 144.790817260742, 139.691024780273, 138.706481933594, 137.455856323242, 145.046249389648, 136.064834594727, 135.468658447266, 134.540267944336, 137.561904907227, 142.4482421875, 141.584777832031)), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")`

I am fairly new to R and haven't been able to find a solution. I would like to create a new column in my dataset and not simply calculate it. I want to use the solution to create a graph.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: I have now created `mean_rp` (mean real price) and added it to the data frame. I am now trying to create a graph that shows how the mean real price of different `region`s has changed over time. I have done this before with `state` data and several instruments, which worked. This is the code is used:

`dc$date <- as.Date(dc$date) plot(subset(dc, code == "RS")$date, subset(dc, code == "RS")$rp, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Real price of cement", ylim=c(0,400)) points(subset(dc, code == "MG")$date, subset(dc, code == "MG")$rp, type = "l",col="red") points(subset(dc, code == "MT")$date, subset(dc, code == "MT")$rp, type = "l",col="yellow") points(subset(dc, code == "PE")$date, subset(dc, code == "PE")$rp, type = "l",col="blue")`

`#Instruments: Shades of grey dc$date <- as.Date(dc$date) points(subset(dc, code == "RS")$date, subset(dc, code == "RS")$rip_diesel/20, type = "l", col="darkgrey") points(subset(dc, code == "RS")$date, subset(dc, code == "RS")$rip_fueloil/10, type = "l", col="darkgrey") points(subset(dc, code == "RS")$date, subset(dc, code == "RS")$rip_vegcoal,type = "l", col="darkgrey") legend("topleft",legend = c("Price of Cement - RS", "Price of Cement - MG","Price of Cement - MT", "Price of Cement - PE", "Price of Diesel (/20)","Price of Fuel Oil (/10)","Price of Veg. Oil"),lty = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),col = c("black", "yellow", "blue", "dark grey", "grey", "lightgrey"),inset = c(0.15,0))`

This resulted in a graph that looks like this:

[Development of rp for different states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPYkB.jpg)

However, my new graph is looking strange.

The only thing I changed was adding `mean_rp` and changing `code` to `region`. Does anyone know what is going on and can help me only end up with one line per color?

[Development of rp for different regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuzRR.jpg)

`plot(subset(dc, region == "N")$date, subset(dc, region == "N")$mean_rp, type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Real price of cement", ylim=c(0,300)) points(subset(dc, region == "NE")$date, subset(dc, region == "NE")$mean_rp, type = "l", col="red") points(subset(dc, region == "MW")$date, subset(dc, region == "MW")$mean_rp, type = "l", col="yellow") points(subset(dc, region == "S")$date, subset(dc, region == "S")$mean_rp, type = "l", col="blue") points(subset(dc, region == "SE")$date, subset(dc, region == "SE")$mean_rp, type = "l",col="green")`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `data.table` library, I've provided syntax below to take the mean of `rp` by `month` and `region`. The general syntax is: `DT[i, j, by=]`, where `DT` is your data.table object, `i` is the subset of data, `j` is what you'd like to return, and `by=` lists the variables you'd like to group by.

```
library(data.table)

`data <- data.table(
  month = c("JAN","FEV","MAR","ABR","MAI","JUN","JUL","AGO","SET","OUT","NOV","DEZ","JAN","FEV"),
  year = c(rep(2004,12),rep(2005,2)),
  code = c(rep("AL",12),rep("AM",2)),
  region = c(rep("NE",12),rep("N",2)),
  month = c(1:12,1:2),
  rp = c(151.351257324219, 150.433822631836, 145.326431274414, 144.790817260742, 139.691024780273, 138.706481933594, 137.455856323242, 145.046249389648, 136.064834594727, 135.468658447266, 134.540267944336, 137.561904907227, 142.4482421875, 141.584777832031))
)

data
    month year code region month       rp
 1:   JAN 2004   AL     NE     1 151.3513
 2:   FEV 2004   AL     NE     2 150.4338
 3:   MAR 2004   AL     NE     3 145.3264
 4:   ABR 2004   AL     NE     4 144.7908
 5:   MAI 2004   AL     NE     5 139.6910
 6:   JUN 2004   AL     NE     6 138.7065
 7:   JUL 2004   AL     NE     7 137.4559
 8:   AGO 2004   AL     NE     8 145.0462
 9:   SET 2004   AL     NE     9 136.0648
10:   OUT 2004   AL     NE    10 135.4687
11:   NOV 2004   AL     NE    11 134.5403
12:   DEZ 2004   AL     NE    12 137.5619
13:   JAN 2005   AM      N     1 142.4482
14:   FEV 2005   AM      N     2 141.5848

> data[,.(Mean = mean(rp)),by=.(month,region)]
    month region     Mean
 1:   JAN     NE 151.3513
 2:   FEV     NE 150.4338
 3:   MAR     NE 145.3264
 4:   ABR     NE 144.7908
 5:   MAI     NE 139.6910
 6:   JUN     NE 138.7065
 7:   JUL     NE 137.4559
 8:   AGO     NE 145.0462
 9:   SET     NE 136.0648
10:   OUT     NE 135.4687
11:   NOV     NE 134.5403
12:   DEZ     NE 137.5619
13:   JAN      N 142.4482
14:   FEV      N 141.5848
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` option.  I assume your original dataset is called `df`.

```
library(dplyr)

df_mean <- df %>%
group_by(month, region) %>%
summarise(mean_rp = mean(rp), .groups = "drop")
```

Now join your `df_mean` to the original dataset:

```
df <- left_join(df, df_mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  group_by(month, region) %>%  
  mutate(mean_rp = mean(rp))

# A tibble: 14 x 7
# Groups:   month, region [14]
   month  year code  region month_num    rp mean_rp
   <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>      <int> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 JAN    2004 AL    NE             1  151.    151.
 2 FEV    2004 AL    NE             2  150.    150.
 3 MAR    2004 AL    NE             3  145.    145.
 4 ABR    2004 AL    NE             4  145.    145.
 5 MAI    2004 AL    NE             5  140.    140.
 6 JUN    2004 AL    NE             6  139.    139.
 7 JUL    2004 AL    NE             7  137.    137.
 8 AGO    2004 AL    NE             8  145.    145.
 9 SET    2004 AL    NE             9  136.    136.
10 OUT    2004 AL    NE            10  135.    135.
11 NOV    2004 AL    NE            11  135.    135.
12 DEZ    2004 AL    NE            12  138.    138.
13 JAN    2004 AM    N              1  142.    142.
14 FEV    2004 AM    N              2  142.    142.

df %>%  
  group_by(year, month, region) %>%  
  mutate(mean_rp = mean(rp)) %>%  
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = paste0(month, year), y = mean_rp, col = region) + 
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was able to add `mean_rp` to my data frame. However, I am having a hard time creating the graph I need. I edited the question in order to explain my task.